# iOS In App Purchase get product id in invalidProductIdentifiers array

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

this question is asked many times and i try many soluation but still getting invalid product id.

I'm done following steps:-
1) Created an App ID with Bundel Id "com.app.name".
2) Created In-App Purchase Products in itune "com.app.name.iap".
3) Created a Sandbox User.
4) Project Configured.
- On In-App Purchase in Capabilities tab
- add StoreKit framework and also done code

> Q1) Is require bank detail for test IAP app?
>   Q2) is required register an IAP App ID for your application?

For Q2 i have some dought so detail following:-
In itune application is created with bundel id "com.app.name" and inside that created IAP with id "com.app.name.iap" and also created "com.app.name" app id in developer account.

is it compalsory to create new app id with "com.app.name.iap"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Paid Applications Agreement" is required to test any IAP. It sounds like that could be your problem. Here is a handy blog post that covers the most common reasons for this problem, with #1 being the missing paperwork: [Configuring In-app Products is Hard](https://www.revenuecat.com/2018/10/11/configuring-in-app-products-is-hard)

Answer (score 1):

> Is require bank detail for test IAP app?

No , but you must login with the sandbox id as icloud account you created within test device.

> is required register an IAP App ID for your application?

No you need not need to register IAP App ID . But you must have created it within app and app bundle id must be registered.

Comment: i'm already login with the sandbox id as icloud account but still getting product as invalidProductIdentifiers in SKProductsResponse

Comment: Since you are not providing specifics , these might be issues in general : a.) You did not complete all the financial requirements (see the "Contracts, Tax, and Banking Information" section of this document). b.)You did not use the correct product identifier in your code. c.) If you or App Review rejected your most recent binary in iTunes Connect. d.)You did not clear your In App Purchase products for sale in iTunes Connect

Comment: Also check you app id and provisioning profiles are correct and also try deleteing app and installing it again from xcode (its weird but sometimes it works)

Comment: recently App Review rejected my binary because i was use third party payment. App Reviewer suggested for implement IAP so now i'm implemented IAP.

Comment: is this resion for getting product as invalidProductIdentifiers in SKProductsResponse?   if yes so how can solve this issue.

Comment: @BhaumikSurani most probably!